# When will Flash Player 11.2.202.356 security update will be available

Tags: updates, flash, security

Adobe Systems released emergency security updates for Flash Player in order to fix a vulnerability that has been exploited in attacks against users since earlier this month.

Software center provides 11.2.202.350 version, when will they update, considering it is a critical security update.

[Adobe statement](http://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/flash-player/apsb14-13.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not really Adobe dropped Linux support for flash ... a year ago so the version we are having is mostly to be outdated since the repos are not updated everyday plus the fact that it must be compiled and pakaged before release. not talking about the tests it must go thru.

It might take a week or a mounth. It depends on how many pakagers are working on flash.

Comment: but it is security update and has already been released for linux systems, as the previous version is compromised.

Comment: If you are really worried....don't use Adobe Flash and related content.

Comment: yep, i am afraid that flash for linux won't be there forever

Answer (score 0):

This update is available now.  Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

This will upgrade the plugin to version 11.2.202.356.